# SVG does not display when embedded in HTML. Displays just fine on its own

Tags: python, html, svg, flask

I am making a web app using Flask. I have created the following function to dynamically render SVG icons with different colors.

All testing is done in the latest Google Chrome on Mac OSX.

```
@app.route("/testicon")
def testicon():
    return render_template("icons/test.svg", primary="ff0000")
```

(Obviously the `primary` parameter is not hardcoded in practice. This is just a demonstration)

This function renders the following SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   height="150"
   width="150">
  <path
     id="path3800" class="icon-primary"
     d="m 32.745902,139.71585 -0.385246,-80.002735 31.333333,-41.349727  z"
     style="fill:#{{ primary }};stroke:none;" />
</svg>
```

(Again, this is simplified for this demonstration.)

When I fire up the Flask server and visit `localhost:5000/testicon`, the SVG displays exactly as it should. However, I created the following function and accompanying template:

```
@app.route("/test")
def test():
    return render_template("test.html")
```

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<img src="{{ url_for('gameplay.testicon') }}" height="300px" width="300px">

</body>
</html>
```

When visiting `localhost:5000/test`, nothing shows up. I can inspect the `img` element and find that its `src` attribute is, indeed, `/testicon`, but the SVG does not display. It instead shows the standard "image not found" icon. However, I can right click on that and select "open image in new tab", and the image, once again, displays just fine. The Google Chrome console shows no errors like it would if I put a bad link in the image's `src`.

What do I have to do to get this image to properly display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer mere moments before hitting "submit" on this question, so I figured I would put the answer here.

I need to set the mime type of the response. I changed my testicon function to this:

```
@app.route("/testicon")
def testicon():
    response = make_response(render_template("icons/test.svg", primary="ff0000"))
    response.mimetype = "image/svg+xml"
    return response
```

Now it works perfectly.